# intellij IDEA Java Configuration with localhost

Tags: localhost, cucumber, java

I started to play with Java API/ Client requests and so on and I'm trying to connect to a localhost for my Java api feature file. For this, I've added to Run configuration, at VM options the path from localhost and port - https://www.screencast.com/t/J08oGJzji, but I don't think is working :(
The test failed and I'm not sure if the problem is about localhost connection or not : 
https://www.screencast.com/t/4Nx27eLf

Can someone,please help me ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Based on your second screenshot (please post next time text not pictures), you might have a look in your feature as the parser complains about the line `Scenario Outline : Login functionality`. Remove the blank before the colon `Scenario Outline: Login functionality` and I guess it should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, the extra spaces were the problem .